# How to commit and push projects in mercurial using MacOSx

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Hi friends how to commit and push projects in bitbucket using  MacOSx

```
$ hg commit
abort: no username supplied
```

In windows hg clients it ask username and password in pop up windows. How does this hapen on macosx? I did supply commands to terminal but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
vim .hg/.hgrc
```

Then type

```
[ui]
username = YOUR_NAME <YOUR_MAIL>
```

to it.
then go back to the main directory and push it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.hgrc`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) in order to configure your local Mercurial client. Setting a username for commits is described [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/QuickStart#Setting_a_username).